# $\{a_n\}$ converges. Can $\{|a_n|\}$ diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

**$\{a_n\}$ converges. Can $\{|a_n|\}$ diverge?**

My try:

$\{a_n\}$ converges $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\exists l\in R,\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = l$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = l \Longrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = |\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n| = |l|$

And now we prove the previous line:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = l \Longleftrightarrow \forall\epsilon > 0 , \exists n_o\in N , \forall n>n_0 : |a_n-l|<\epsilon$

We know by the triangle inequality that:

$\left||a_n|-|l|\right|\leq |a_n-l|<\epsilon$

Then:

$\forall\epsilon > 0 , \exists n_o\in N , \forall n>n_0 : ||a_n|-|l||<\epsilon\Longleftrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = |l| $

This means that the answer to the question is NO

I am aware that this is similar to [this other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014277/is-showing-that-a-n-converges-the-same-as-showing-lim-n-to-inftya-n-a) , but it didnt solve my problem.

Comment: That's right. In other words $x\mapsto|x|$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: To take the limit inside a function it only needs to be continuous? Doesnt it have to be continuous AND derivable?

Comment: No, the function only needs to be continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, suppose by contradiction that $|a_n|$ diverges therefore since

- $|a_n|=a_n$ for $a_n\ge 0$
- $|a_n|=-a_n$ for $a_n< 0$

we have that $a_n$ doesn’t converge.